# When I click a button reload other template angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to when I click a button, reload other template without exiting of the current template in angular.js

```
<div ng-repeat="caracter in crit.characters" class="col-md-4">
    <a class="thumbnail" id="mySelect" ng-click="clickSelection(caracter.id)">
        <h4 align="center">{{caracter.name}}</h4>
        <img ng-src="{{caracter.image_url}}"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Any help it will be appreciated

Comment: use angular router for that https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: I am already using route I now need to when it's clicked reload the other template

Comment: To reload current template use `$route.reload();`

Comment: not the current I want to reload other template

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the current view template or you just want to load some html code that displays some info about one of the items in your ng-repeat list?

Comment: I'm in a template and when I click in the `<a>` a different template have to reload

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 3 templates

```
var templates =
            [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'temp1.html'} ,
              { name: 'template2.html', url: 'temp2.html'},
              { name: 'template3.html', url: 'temp3.html'} 
            ];
```

in your html use `ng-template`

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp1.html">
   <!--YOUR TEMPLATE 1-->
  </script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp2.html">
   <!--YOUR TEMPLATE 2-->
  </script>

<div ng-include="template.url">

</div>
```

on click of button call

```
$scope.changeTemplates=function(x){
            if(x.toUpperCase()=='temp1'){
                $scope.template=templates[1];
            }else if(x.toUpperCase()=='temp2'){
                $scope.template=templates[2];
            }else if(x.toUpperCase()=='temp3'){
                $scope.template=templates[0];
            }
        }
```

This will assign `$scope.template` the html from `ng-template`

Comment: is not exactly what I wanted because I already have more templates and use the route to navigate between them but now I need to know how to when I click a button or something else in a template another one reloads but thanks anyway very appreciated

Comment: on button click call `changeTemplates` function. No?

Comment: i don't want to change my current template i want to reload another template from the current template